# How to increase swap space in docker container in runtime?

Tags: docker, cgroups, aws-batch

I have a use case where I need to increase the swap space limit when container is started(runtime).
My docker is always run as "docker run -m 1G ..." (from AWS Batch).
Docker always sets swap space value as 2x the hard memory limit. How can I increase this value when the container is started?

I tried few pre-start/post-start docker plugins to change the cgroup value but nothing seems to be working

Note:
I cannot issue a "docker run --memory-swap value" since it is controlled by AWS Batch.

Few ref which leads me no where- https://engineering.clever.com/2018/02/06/swappiness-amazon-ecs/